# Openvpn ldap configuration

Tags: active-directory, debian, windows-server-2012-r2, openvpn

I have installed openvpn and i have configured LDAP with microsoft active direcoty. Eevrything is OK.
But now, I want to setup encrypted connection to this Active Directory server.
When I turn on TLS on ovpn server, it doesn't work.
What I need to setup on ovpn server and AD, please?
I didn't found any tutorial.

Thank you very much

```
<LDAP>
# LDAP server URL
URL       ldap://ad.xxxxxx.eu    
# Bind DN (If your LDAP server doesn't support anonymous binds)
BindDN  xxxx@xxxx.com
# Bind Password
Password  "xxxxx"
# Network timeout (in seconds)
Timeout   15
# Enable Start TLS
TLSEnable no
# Follow LDAP Referrals (anonymously)
FollowReferrals no
# TLS CA Certificate File
#TLSCACertFile /root/ldaps.cer
# TLS CA Certificate Directory
#TLSCACertDir  /root/

# Client Certificate and key
#If TLS client authentication is required
#TLSCertFile        /root/cert1.cer
#TLSKeyFile /etc/openvpn/server/ovpn_AD.key
```

This config is good, everything is fine. But when I add certificate and turn on tls, authentication is not working...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your domain controllers have a certificate installed whose cn matches the URL you are using in your configuration.

Enbale TLS (STARTTLS)

And make sure your openvpn server trusts this certificate by also providing it or the appropriate intermediate/root certificate to the openvpn server.

Find some useful practices for troubleshooting LDAP with STARTTL on AD here:
https://active-directory-wp.com/docs/Networking/Encryption_with_TLS.html